# Weird screen after building a game in unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I'am building a game in unity. The game works fine in unity. After building it for android, I'am facing two problems.
1: I get this weird screen for a second right after the unity logo is shown and before my first scene is loaded.
2: The same thing continues to show through the entire game in nexus six only.

note: I have checked with different versions of android including lollipop in nexus 4 and 6. In every other device(other than nexus 6), the screen appears just for 1 second before loading my main scene.

*Could not upload the Screenshot... The the screen looks like it has got a hundred camera's in the scene and each one of it shows the same part of the scene. So basically the part of the scene repeats itself to cover the whole scene.

Please help...:)

Comment: Is your code is displaying the screen based on the different Devices Resolutions?

Comment: The resolution is actually set for iPad(3 X 4). But I'm testing it on android.
I doubt its a resolution problem, because it shows stuff from my main scene before the main scene gets properly loaded. I'm trying to look for the problem during the transition from scene0 to main scene. No solution as yet.

Comment: Do it for all then let we check

Comment: Check with simple scene's with your Screen Resolutions If it works then problem is with the scenes only

Comment: Have you tried to reproduce the problem with a new, empty Unity project?

Comment: I tried something and its seems to have solved my problem. The way the screen was looking, I thought that scene0 needs to  show something but it doesn't have a camera. So I added a camera to scene0 and the problem is gone. Is that a proper solution?
Note: 
Working fine with all devices except Nexus 6. Is it because the device is rooted?

Comment: Rasa Mohamed - Yes, the simple scenes were working fine. As I said, the screen showed stuff from the main scene before it was loaded.
Max Yankov - I will try to do that, but I haven't faced this problem before.